# How to get last modified date on Windows command line for a set of files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have been using the following command to get the file date. However, the `fileDate` variable has been returning blank value ever since we moved to a different server (Windows Server 2003).

```
FOR /f %%a in ('dir myfile.txt^|find /i " myfile.txt"') DO SET fileDate=%%a
```

Is there any other more reliable way to get the file date?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the code that follows, change `%` to `%%` for use in batch file, for `%~ta` syntax enter `call /?`

```
for %a in (MyFile.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
```

Sample output:

```
for %a in (MyFile.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
set FileDate=05/05/2020 09:47 AM

for %a in (file_not_exist_file.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
set FileDate=
```

Comment: +1. That's actually the correct one. Parsing the output of `dir` is insanity at best. Side note: In a batch file, double the `%` signs.

Comment: Thanks, one more question: how get just the date portion. Is the following syntax reliable enough or is there a better way.
   
   set FileDate=%FileDate:~0,10%

Comment: It may not work if you change your international settings, but otherwise it should be OK

Comment: can you give me a hint as to what is actually happening here?  I'm not sure I understand what %~ta or %a is

Comment: For me no matter what I do, the result is blank. Default english US.

Comment: @MarkDeven, if you're not getting a result then either the file you're specifying doesn't exist or you current login doesn't have access to it.

Answer (score 27):

Useful reference to get file properties using a batch file, included is the last modified time:

```
FOR %%? IN ("C:\somefile\path\file.txt") DO (
    ECHO File Name Only       : %%~n?
    ECHO File Extension       : %%~x?
    ECHO Name in 8.3 notation : %%~sn?
    ECHO File Attributes      : %%~a?
    ECHO Located on Drive     : %%~d?
    ECHO File Size            : %%~z?
    ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~t?
    ECHO Drive and Path       : %%~dp?
    ECHO Drive                : %%~d?
    ECHO Fully Qualified Path : %%~f?
    ECHO FQP in 8.3 notation  : %%~sf?
    ECHO Location in the PATH : %%~dp$PATH:?
)
```

Comment: how to use or implement this?

Answer (score 21):

You can do it

```
forfiles /M myfile.txt /C "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime"
```

Comment: is this locale dependent?

Comment: Cool, didn't know there is `forfiles` - quite more intuitive than all the cryptic `for` examples on the net.

Comment: this includes seconds, where ~t is only precise to the minute. Powershell also gives seconds via the two part command: `$myFileInfo = Get-Item C:\myPath\myFile.txt` `$myFileInfo.LastWriteTime`

Comment: Hmm...how to set/get those date variables in a batch-file?

Comment: @BeatriceThalo You can one-line it by just wrapping the first part:
`(get-item filePath.txt).LastWriteTime`

Comment: The string format for this command varies depending on the system date/time format preferences (control panel -> region -> change date/time number formats). It's not reliable if you want to parse the output.

Answer (score 8):

To get the last modification date/time of a file in a **locale-independent** manner you could use the [`wmic` command](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) with the `DataFile` alias:

```cmd
wmic DataFile where "Name='D:\\Path\\To\\myfile.txt'" get LastModified /VALUE
```

Regard that the full path to the file must be provided and that all path separators (backslashes `\`) must be doubled herein.

This returns a standardised date/time value like this (meaning 12<sup>th</sup> of August 2019, 13:00:00, UTC + 120'):

> ```cmd
> LastModified=20190812130000.000000+120
> ```

To capture the date/time value use [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), then you can assign it to a variable using [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic DataFile where "Name='D:\\Path\\To\\myfile.txt'" get LastModified /VALUE
') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do set "DateTime=%%K"
```

The second `for /F` loop avoids artefacts (like orphaned carriage-return characters) from conversion of the Unicode output of `wmic` to ASCII/ANSI text by the first `for /F` loop (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199181)).

You can then use [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to extract the pure date or the time from this:

```cmd
set "DateOnly=%DateTime:~0,8%"
set "TimeOnly=%DateTime:~8,6%"
```

To get the creation date/time or the last access date/time, just replace the property `LastModified` by `CreationDate` or `LastAccessed`, respectively. To get information about a directory rather than a file, use the alias `FSDir` instead of `DataFile`.

For specifying file (or directory) paths/names containing both `,` and `)`, which are usually not accepted by `wmic`, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37198153).

Check out also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33248149) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25631757) about how to get file and directory date/time stamps.

Comment: precision in microseconds (aka .001 milliseconds)

Comment: Note that this is deprecated and is expected to be removed. https://research.nccgroup.com/2022/03/10/microsoft-announces-the-wmic-command-is-being-retired-long-live-powershell/

Comment: Yes, @Nelson; an up-to-date alternative is to leverage from PowerShell: `PowerShell -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "(Get-Item 'D:\Path\To\myfile.txt').LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format o"` (of course also with `.CreationTime` or `.LastAccessTime`)…

Comment: @aschipfl is this also locale independent format or what should one write to make it locale independent? I'm getting an error at %%I saying "%%I was unexpected at this time." for the solution that was posted - plus if it's deprecated I would go with the powershell cmd to spare myself from suffering later. I'm getting back the following for the PS cmd: "2023-04-25T00:31:11.6539686+03:00"

Comment: okay, actually i just found that you can set the format to suit your need, thanks

Comment: @RandomDude, the used command `wmic` is meanwhile deprecated, so PowerShell is a good option to retrieve locale-independent date/time information. Concerning the `%%I` error: have you executed the command line in a Command Prompt rather than in a batch file? if so, use `%I` instead of `%%I` (same for other loop variables, of course)…

Comment: @aschipfl I had this in batch file, I also read somewhere what you just mentioned. I just didn't realize, that I can change the date format in the command at first, so I wasn't sure that the response I get back for the PS command is locale-independent. I needed this for folder generation, I wanted to generate folder names with the timestamp in it, and luckily this PS cmd with the formatting was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me on Vista.  Some things to try:

1. Replace `find` with the fully-qualified path of the find command.  `find` is a common tool name. There's a unix find that is very differet from the Windows built-in find.  like this:
   `FOR /f %%a in ('dir ^|%windir%\system32\find.exe /i "myfile.txt"') DO SET fileDate=%%a`
2. examine the output of the command in a cmd.exe window.  To do that, You need to replace the %% with %.
   `FOR /f %a in ('dir ^|c:\windows\system32\find.exe /i "myfile.txt"') DO SET fileDate=%a`
   That may give you some ideas.
3. If that shows up as blank, then again, at a command prompt, try this:

   `dir | c:\windows\system32\find.exe /i "myfile.txt"`

This should show you what you need to see.

If you still can't figure it out from that, edit your post to include what you see from these commands and someone will help you.

Comment: my statetement and (the step 1 and 2) work on my computer and any other win server 2003 that I can get my hand on. could this be an issue where it run under service id and trigger by a scheduler?

Comment: yes it could be.  The find program may be different for a different service ID, because it has a different path.  Best to run these commands under the service ID to capture and examine the output.

Comment: Some years ago we had some similar issues regarding the batch processing of the output of the DIR command, because of different language of the command processor (in our case, our batch file worked in win2000 english and spanish, but failed in german).

Comment: Also can happen with UK versus US english!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the 'Last Written' [time options associated with the DIR command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

/T:C -- Creation Time and Date
/T:A -- Last Access Time and Date
/T:W -- Last Written Time and Date (default)

```
DIR /T:W myfile.txt
```

The output from the above command will produce a variety of additional details you probably wont need, so you could incorporate two FINDSTR commands to remove blank lines, plus any references to 'Volume', 'Directory' and 'bytes':

```
DIR /T:W myfile.txt | FINDSTR /v "^$" | FINDSTR /v /c:"Volume" /c:"Directory" /c:"bytes"
```

Attempts to incorporate the blank line target (/c:"^$" or "^$") within a single FINDSTR command fail to remove the blank lines (or produce other errors) when the results are output to a text file.

This is a cleaner command:

```
DIR /T:W myfile.txt | FINDSTR /c:"/"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get a files modified date using vbscript too

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile= objArgs(0)
WScript.Echo objFS.GetFile(strFile).DateLastModified
```

save the above as mygetdate.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo mygetdate.vbs myfile
```

Comment: is this locale dependent?

Comment: @MarkDeven, this is locale-independent as here a real date/time data type is involved...

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to bring in an EXE, I recommend `gdate.exe` (from [GNU CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)).  It can give the current date or the date of a file, in many different formats, and customizable.  I use it to get the last modified date-time of files that I can compare without any parsing (ie. local-independent), using the `%s` (seconds since the epoch), optionally with `%N` to get nano-second precision.

Some examples:

```
C:\>dir MyFile.txt
02/10/2021  10:54 PM                 4 MyFile.txt

C:\>gdate -r MyFile.txt +%Y-%m-%d
2021-02-10

C:\>gdate -r MyFile.txt "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2021-02-10 22:54:50

C:\>gdate -r MyFile.txt +%s
1613015690

C:\>gdate -r MyFile.txt +%s.%N
1613015690.093962600
```

Answer (score 0):

What output *(exactly)* does `dir myfile.txt` give in the current directory?  What happens if you set the delimiters?

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in ('dir myfile.txt^|find /i " myfile.txt"') DO SET fileDate=%%a
```

(note the space after `delims=`)
(to make life easier, you can do this from the command line by replacing `%%a` with `%a`)

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell to get a specific date format:

```
for /f "usebackq" %d in (`powershell "(get-item \"Rar.exe\").lastWriteTime.toString(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")"`) do ( echo ren "Rar.exe" "%d_rar550.exe" )
rem
```