# How to get locale-independent modified time and creation time of a file in batch?

Tags: datetime, batch-file, localization, regional-settings, filemtime

With [batch variable/parameter expansion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835.aspx) like `%~t1` one can get a timestamp of a file.

I would like to set the year of the file to another variable would like to support multiple locales.

How can you get a file's datetime, independent of locale and regional settings? No powershell please.

Comment: `%~t1` - shows `last modified` so I suppose you want this time , but not `last accessed` or `date created` ?

Comment: and what means `mtime` and `ctime` ?

Comment: @npocmaka I attempted to mean `"modification time"` by `mtime` and `"creation time"` by `ctime`.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post few options

1)**First one is with `wmic`** (not available for XP home edition) (`LastModified` can be changed with `CreationDate` or `LastAccessed` )

```
@echo off

set file_loc=.\temp_file
for %%# in ("%file_loc%") do set file_loc=%%~dpfnx#
set file_loc=%file_loc:\=\\%


for /f "delims=." %%t in ('"WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file_loc%" get LastModified /format:value"') do (
    for /f %%$ in ("%%t") do if "%%$" neq "" set %%$
)

echo %LastModified%
echo year : %LastModified:~0,4%
echo month : %LastModified:~4,2%
echo day : %LastModified:~6,2%
```

2). **Jscript/.bat hybrid** (`DateLastModified` can be changed to `DateCreated`  or `DateLastAccessed` .Time format can be changed to whatever you want ):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** jscript comment ******
@echo off

set file_loc=.\temp_file
for %%# in ("%file_loc%") do set file_loc=%%~dpfnx#
::set file_loc=%file_loc:\=\\%
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%file_loc%"
exit /b 0

****** end of jscript comment ******/

var file_loc = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var the_file=fso.GetFile(file_loc);
var the_date= new Date(the_file.DateLastModified);
WScript.Echo(the_date.getFullYear());
WScript.Echo(the_date.getMonth());
WScript.Echo(the_date.getUTCDate());
```

3) **selfcompiled jscript.net/bat hybrid** (`GetLastWriteTime` can be changed to  `GetLastAccessTime` or `GetCreationTime` . Time format can be changed) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent line that start jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist "%~n0.exe" goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation



set file_loc=.\temp_file
for %%# in ("%file_loc%") do set file_loc=%%~dpfnx#


"%~n0.exe" "%file_loc%"


exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/
import System;
import System.IO;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

var the_file=arguments[1];
var last_modified=File.GetLastWriteTime(the_file);
 Console.WriteLine(last_modified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

4). **robocopy** - with this you can get only last modified date (with other methods you can get all time attributes).As time stamps in robocopy are always `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:SS` this can be used...

```
@ECHO OFF

set file_loc=.\temp_file
for %%# in ("%file_loc%") do set file_dir=%%~dp#
for %%# in ("%file_loc%") do set file_name=%%~nx#
pushd %file_dir%

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('robocopy  "." "%temp%" /l /fat /ts /LEV:1 /NP /NC /NS /NJS /NJH^|findstr /i /e /c:"%file_name%"') do (
    echo %%a %%b
)
popd
```

**EDIT** Here are ready to use parametrized scripts using all the listed methods:

1. [fileModifiedTime.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets last modified time of file with settings independent format.Based on **robocopy**
2. [fileTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets file time stamps with **WMIC**
3. [dirTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/dirTimes.bat)  - gets directory time stamps with **WMIC**
4. [fileTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/fileTImesJS.bat) - file time stamps with **jscript**
5. [dirTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/dirTimesJS.bat)  - directory time stamps with **jscript**
6. [fileTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/fileTimesNET.bat) - file time stamps with **.NET**
7. [dirTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/dirTimesNET.bat)  - dir time stamps with **.NET**