# How to get standardized date/time stamp of file or dir. in pure batch scripting?

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way in Windows command line to retrieve the date/time stamps (modification, creation, access) of a file or directory in a standardized **locale-independent** format (for instance, [ISO8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm))?

I found that the output of `dir` uses system-dependent date/time format, with the seconds missing.
The same is true for the `~t` modifier of the parameter (`%~t1`) and `for` variable expansion (`%~tI`).
Also the `forfiles` variables `@fdate` and `@ftime` depend on the system settings (although the latter returns also the seconds at least).

I have learned that `wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE` is a way to get the **current** system date/time (the output may look like `LocalDateTime=20151021020000.000000+120`, it can be captured by `for /F`).
But is there also a command (line) that returns a file or directory date/time stamp in a similar format?

Comment: You can run a `for` loop on the command line, you just need to use `%` instead of `%%` for the variable.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25632042/388389)

Comment: and as addition for wmic with folders you'll need to use `wmic path win32_directory..`  . Here's the [description of win32_directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which will help you to create a query

Comment: @npocmaka, that's exactly what I'm looking for! if you post an answer (at least for the directory stuff, files are covered by your [linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25632042/388389) (§ 1) anyway), I could accept it...

Comment: @aschipfl - I just need few minutes to create the scripts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631757/how-to-get-locale-independent-mtime-and-ctime-of-a-file-in-batch/25632042#25632042) you can find a ways to get the times of a file.

1)For directory you can use this **WMIC** query :

```
@echo off
set "directory=."

for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%directory%") do set "directory=%%#"

set "directory=%temp%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in (`"WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name='%directory:\=\\%' get creationdate,LastAccessed,LastModified /format:value"`) do (
  for /f %%@ in ("%%#") do echo %%@
)
```

2) or with **jscript hybrid** (just like in the file version you can use also `LastModified` , `CreationDate` or `LastAccessed`):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** jscript comment ******
@echo off

set "directory=."
for %%# in (%directory%) do set "directory=%%~f#"
if exist "%directory%\" (

 cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%directory%"
)
exit /b %errorlevel%

****** end of jscript comment ******/

var file_loc = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var the_file=fso.GetFolder(file_loc);
var the_date= new Date(the_file.DateLastModified);
WScript.Echo(the_date.getFullYear());
WScript.Echo(the_date.getMonth());
WScript.Echo(the_date.getUTCDate());
```

3) with **self-compiled jscript.net** (which can be the most powerful option because of .NET formatting capabilities):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** start of jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist "%~n0.exe" goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation



set "directory=."
for %%# in (%directory%) do set "directory=%%~f#"


"%~n0.exe" "%directory%"


exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/
import System;
import System.IO;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

var the_dir=arguments[1];

var last_modified=Directory.GetLastWriteTime(the_dir);
Console.WriteLine("modified time "+last_modified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

var created=Directory.GetCreationTime(the_dir);
Console.WriteLine("created time "+created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

var accessed=Directory.GetLastAccessTime(the_dir);
Console.WriteLine("accessed time "+accessed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

**EDIT** Here are ready to use parametrized scripts using all the listed methods:

1. [fileModifiedTime.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets last modified time of file with settings independent format.Based on **robocopy**
2. [fileTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets file time stamps with **WMIC**
3. [dirTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/dirTimes.bat)  - gets directory time stamps with **WMIC**
4. [fileTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/fileTImesJS.bat) - file time stamps with **jscript**
5. [dirTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/dirTimesJS.bat)  - directory time stamps with **jscript**
6. [fileTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/fileTimesNET.bat) - file time stamps with **.NET**
7. [dirTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/dirTimesNET.bat)  - dir time stamps with **.NET**

Comment: ...concerning the `wmic` approaches: the inner `for /F` loop removes any `wmic` output artefacts like orphaned carriage-returns, is that true?

Comment: @aschipfl - yes.The technique was introduced by dbenham [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

Comment: I'm afraid the `wmic` method fails when the file/dir. name contains char.s like `^` or `&`; however, if I remove the `""` around the entire `wmic` command and put the `name=` argument (the path) in between `""` instead of `''`, it works... the only problem left is the `%` character (unless I double it)...

Comment: @aschipfl - hmm.. didn't thought about that.One possible workaround is to use short names - these characters won't be there in short names , but there's a chance this feature to be turned off.Other is to set double quotes around file name , but I'm not sure how the for loop will handle it (i'll try) or using delayed expansion , but then the `!` will be a problem.

Comment: ...the work-around I mentioned [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248149/how-to-get-standardized-date-time-stamp-of-file-or-dir-in-pure-batch-scripting/33248735#comment54332444_33248735) was meant to be done in the `for /F` loop... yes, delayed expansion will solve the `%` problem, but introduces the `!` issue...

Comment: @aschipfl - I'll update it based on your suggestions . And will think about how to handle both `!` and `%` but probably I wont succeed. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18663935/388389)  dbenham used some bulletproof techniques about similar problem and I'll see if I will be able to used it.