# How to get a file's last modified date on windows/dos command

Tags: batch-file, last-modified

I'm looking to get a file's last modified date from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderTransfer4\WRTEUHH.dll
```

I used script

```
for %a in (WRTEUHH.dll) do set FileDate=%~ta
```

which posted here: [How to get file's last modified date on Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111333/how-to-get-files-last-modified-date-on-windows-command-line)

This script works. However, this only works if that DLL is in the same folder where command prompt ran from. I would like to get it from that program files folder and the date from there directly if possible.

Comment: Then use the path in your code. `for %a in ("C:\path to file\WRTEUHH.dll") do set FileDate=%~ta`

Comment: This worked. I swear I tried this yesterday and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few examples for you:

Last Written Date and Time - ***(cmd.exe)*** using provided example with for variable reference expansion

```dos
FOR %A IN ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4\WRTEUHH.dll") DO @ECHO=%~tA
```

Last Written Date and Time - ***(cmd.exe)*** using where command in for loop, *(does not cater for local time outputs using AM/PM notation)*

```dos
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-3" %A IN ('WHERE /T "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4:WRTEUHH.dll"') DO @ECHO=%A %B
```

Last Written Date only - ***(cmd.exe)*** using where command in for loop

```dos
FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %A IN ('WHERE /T "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4:WRTEUHH.dll"') DO @ECHO=%A
```

Last Written Date and Time - ***(batch file)*** using provided example with for variable reference expansion

```dos
@FOR %%A IN ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4\WRTEUHH.dll") DO @(ECHO=%%~tA&PAUSE)
```

Last Written Date and Time - ***(batch file)*** using where command in for loop, *(does not cater for local time outputs using AM/PM notation)*

```dos
@FOR /F "TOKENS=2-3" %%A IN ('WHERE /T "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4:WRTEUHH.dll"') DO @(ECHO=%%A %%B&PAUSE)
```

Last Written Date only - ***(batch file)*** using where command in for loop

```dos
@FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('WHERE /T "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\FolderTransfer4:WRTEUHH.dll"') DO @(ECHO=%%A&@PAUSE)
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. I ended up using the first script which worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much for the details.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the forfiles command in the past which worked pretty well and it may help in this case.

Here's an example and output:

Command
`forfiles /P C:\_Demo\WritersForum /M *.* /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime"`

Output
    "06-21-09-20__Broken_links.txt" 6/21/2016 9:21:08 AM
    "06-21-09-21__Broken_links.txt" 6/21/2016 9:22:06 AM
    "10-20-04-23__Broken_links.txt" 10/20/2016 4:24:00 PM
    "10-20-04-25__Broken_links.txt" 10/20/2016 4:25:57 PM
    "10-20-04-26__Broken_links.txt" 10/20/2016 4:26:57 PM

If this doesn't work I should be able to help out with the script above.

Comment: Part of my response was left off.  You can use the /S switch to recurse.  The /P switch is the path so you'll just need to change that to program files (x86).