# How to append file's last modification date to file name on moving the file?

Tags: date, batch-file

I have an Excel add-in for my organization that I regularly update. I have a batch file which moves the previous add-in to an "old" directory, and I want to append the file's last modified date to the file name in order to keep track of all previous versions.

Using `%DATE%` I can append the current date to the filename, but I want to know how I can append the date for when the file was last modified.

This is my batch file so far, using the `%DATE%` command.

```
Ren J:\40_MS\435_Milj›\Annet\Datah†ndtering\Add-ins\435_Milj›.xlam 435_Milj›_old.xlam
Move J:\40_MS\435_Milj›\Annet\Datah†ndtering\Add-ins\435_Milj›_old.xlam J:\40_MS\435_Milj›\Annet\Datah†ndtering\Add-ins\Old\
Ren J:\40_MS\435_Milj›\Annet\Datah†ndtering\Add-ins\Old\435_Milj›_old.xlam 435_Milj›_%DATE%.xlam
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The suggested duplicate doesn't actually explain how to append the file date to the file name. I tried using this script:

```
Ren C:\Temp\435_Milj›.xlam 435_Milj›_old.xlam
Move C:\Temp\435_Milj›_old.xlam C:\Temp\Old\
for %a in (C:\Temp\Old\435_Milj›_old.xlam) do set MyFileDate=%~ta
Ren C:\Temp\Old\435_Milj›_old 435_Milj›_%MyFileDate%.xlam
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a file's last modified date on windows/dos command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272150/how-to-get-a-files-last-modified-date-on-windows-dos-command)

Comment: This explains how to get the date, but I don't understand how to append it to the file name.