# xcopy file, rename, suppress "Does xxx specify a file name..." message

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, xcopy

This seems pretty simple and maybe I'm just overlooking the [proper flag](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true), but how would I, in one command, copy a file from one directory to another and rename it in the destination directory?  Here's my command:

```
if exist "bin\development\whee.config.example"
  if not exist "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config"
    xcopy "bin\development\whee.config.example"
          "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config"
```

It prompts me with the following every time:

> Does TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config specify a file name
>   or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?

I want to suppress this prompt; the answer is always `F`.

Comment: echo f | xcopy ...

Comment: Related: [XCOPY still asking (F = file, D = directory) confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33752732)

Comment: I recommend reading my answer on [BATCH file asks for file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829012/3074564) explaining in detail when the prompt is shown and how it can be answered automatically by a batch file OS language independent.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Don't use the `xcopy`, use `copy` instead, it doesn't have this issue.

`xcopy` is generally used when performing recursive copies of multiple files/folders, or when you need the verification/prompting features it offers. For single file copies, the `copy` command works just fine.

Comment: `copy` will not copy the file if the entire directory structure for the destination doesn't already exist. `xcopy` will automatically create all needed directories.

Comment: It's *amazing* that xcopy has this omission.  If it simply had an option for files like it has for directories (/I), this would be solved and xcopy could be a great replacement for copy.  Instead, due to this defect, you have to choose copy for these situations.

Comment: As others have already pointed out, @Arnshea's answer is the correct one. This is because a) the OP's particular circumstance of already having the directory structure in place was not mentioned in the question, and b) it is far more valuable for future readers of this question who will come here looking for an answer regarding `xcopy` and not just `copy`.

Comment: Well @Amshea's answer is also the correct one because the question is specific to xcopy, and this answer is basically "don't use xcopy".  Doesn't really answer the question about xcopy at all, now does it?

Comment: In my case I need the /F /R /D switches that xcopy offers and copy lacks. So I settle for the answer by Amshea.

Comment: xcopy has the option of only performing the copy if the source is newer than the destination, so in this case (and others) copy cannot simply be used in place of xcopy as it will not perform the same operation.

Comment: Just add a star at the end of the path for the target. Look at this answer below.http://stackoverflow.com/a/26034267/1231

Comment: This answer is rubbish. The whole reason for using Xcopy is for what copy cannot do

Comment: I also do not like this answer. @Arnshea's or zippycoder's answers are far better, as they use xcopy, which can do things copy cannot, e.g., in my case, I want to overwrite the destination file even if the read only attribute is set.

Comment: `copy` was removed from Windows 10.

Answer (score 683):

I use

```
echo f | xcopy /f /y srcfile destfile
```

to get around it.

Comment: @Arnshea - thanks! Adapted for silent directory copy `echo d | xcopy srcdirectory destdirectory /S`

Comment: +1 @Arnshea it took me some time to understand what you are exactly doing there and since im working on a german windows installation its `echo d | xcopy ...` for me. You are brilliant

Comment: Can you expand on what this is doing and why it is better than the accepted answer?

Comment: He's simulating a user response to the question that xcopy will ask.

Comment: @Thomas Does that imply that a batch file that uses this technique won't be portable across different locales?

Comment: @MaxNanasy I confirmed that this is not portable across locales. In a german setup, you pass in D for a file or V for a directory. :(

Comment: This is neat -- I knew you could pipe in files with "< file.txt" but I didn't realize you could use pipe in echos like that -- this can save me a few lines of code in my batch files where I pipe out to file.txt first! -- One question -- is there ever a time when xcopy might give this prompt more than once? (i.e. this will pipe one "y" into xcopy, what about the second time it asks?)

Comment: Thanks @Arnshea, just what I needed.
I'm copying whole directories so using this instead 
`echo D | xcopy /f /y /d /e SourceDir DestDir`

Answer (score 199):

Another option is to use a destination wildcard. Note that this only works if the source and destination filenames will be the same, so while this doesn't solve the OP's specific example, I thought it was worth sharing.

For example:

```
xcopy /y "bin\development\whee.config.example" "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\*"
```

will create a copy of the file "whee.config.example" in the destination directory without prompting for file or directory.

**Update**: As mentioned by @chapluck:

You can change `"* "` to `"[newFileName].*"`. It persists file extension but allows to rename. Or more hacky: `"[newFileName].[newExt]*"` to change extension

Comment: The "echo f |" way is cool, but this avoids the extra output that I often search for to find problems in the first place.

Comment: @Durden81 - as zippycoder points out, their answer does not rename the file, which was a requirement of the OP.

Comment: To extend the answer I would change "* " to "[newFileName].*". It persists file extension but allows to rename. Or more hacky: "[newFileName].*[newExt]" to change extension.

Comment: Thanks! The update section is what solved my problem, where the file name needed to be changed, while keeping the extension and assuming that it's the file. XCopy should have had this as a switch.

Comment: Why is this not the answer. This is the correct answer based on http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html.

Comment: Worked for me without the asterisk at the end, just backslash.

Comment: This even works if copying a single file AND renaming it such as this: xopy file*.bat to newfile.bat*.   I have to do this because the vendor renames the installation file each time a new version is released.  So while I do not have to re-edit the batch file for multiple deployments, xopying the file to a 'fixed' filename aids me in my deployment strategy.

Comment: @zippycoder Better than the answers above, because it actually uses xcopy (not copy), and is not locale specific. It solved my problem copying an XML file, where the filename changes, but not the extension.

Answer (score 109):

There is some sort of undocumented feature in XCOPY. you can use:

xcopy "bin\development\whee.config.example" "c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config*"

i tested it just today. :-)

Comment: Thanks alot. I added an "*" at the end of destination file and it worked..:) +1 for the trick

Comment: Excellent solution - clean, elegant, doesn't use a different command, compatible with existing xcopy flags, works flawlessly. This should be the top voted answer.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, the command will result `whee.config.example` in the destination folder, because `whee.config*` matches `whee.config.example`.

Comment: I just created a file `b.txtxt`, and then I launched the command `xcopy a.txt b.txt* /F /Y` and the file `a.txt` has been copied to `b.txt`, as expected. In top of that, while using the `/F /Y` switches, the actual copy is shown on screen, exactly as expected.

Comment: @Meow: no, since the wildcard is in the destination, not the source.

Comment: This did not work for me and copied (much) more than it should have. In my case I was copying specific files out of directories that contained many files and subdirs, and it copied far too much even though the asterisk was, correctly, only on the destination parameter, and enclosed in double-quotes. Using ```echo f|```, however, worked exactly as I wanted

Comment: @ienaxxx The destination could have has files with different suffix and yes it would match a different file then. This answer demonstrates not fully tested example.

Answer (score 74):

Just go to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx

Here's what the MAIN ISSUE is "... If Destination does not contain an existing directory and **does not end with a backslash** (), the following message appears: ...

*Does destination specify a file name 
or directory name on the target 
(F = file, D = directory)?*

You can suppress this message by using the /i command-line option, which causes xcopy to assume that the destination is a directory if the source is more than one file or a directory.

Took me a while, but all it takes is RTFM.

Comment: This should be the top answer! Just to be really clear for others. If you are copying ONE file from one place to another AND you want the full directory structure to be created, use the following command: xcopy /"C:\Data\Images\2013\08\12\85e4a707-2672-481b-92fb-67ecff20c96b.jpg" "C:\Target Data\\Images\2013\08\12\85e4a707-2672-481b-92fb-67ecff20c96b.jpg\" . Yes, put a backslash at the end of the file name!

Comment: Good answer, but does not solve the problem. I tried xcopy hello.txt hello2\ . No prompt. Now i try xcopy hello.txt hello3 (without backslash). It prompts me whether dest is file or dir. I need a way to tell it to assume F or D in a script.

Comment: This is a very strange answer, especially because of the upvotes, the unhelpful "RTFM" snark, and the comments putting down the "popular" answers...since it doesn't address the original question!  The original question clearly said "copy a file from one directory to another AND RENAME IT in the destination directory".   The attempted answer given above appears to address the different case of copying the file with the destination file name being the SAME name as the source file.   The "messy" workaround given by @Arnshea is the only single-step answer I see given here--thus its "popularity".

Comment: Mr. Bearden was quite polite, but given the number of up votes, I feel the need to expressly list the problems with this answer: 1) the 1 paragraph that seems to give a solution for the OP's problem (paragraph 4 of 5), does _not_ work, because the OP is copying _and renaming_ a **file**, _not_ a directory; 2) the link given at the top of the answer does _not_ provide a solution; 3) the statement of the **main issue** does _not_ apply to the OP's question; and 4) the answer is offensive, with shouting in the 2nd paragraph and insults in the last. Perhaps he should have re-Read The Question.

Comment: All answer given here are to copy to a directory, not to copy in a file destination, which is possible and undocumented, see the other answer from  zippycoder, chapluck, LBushkin

Comment: As said in the above, your answer is not working, at least for copying files. Too bad i upvoted and then 10 mins passed before I found out it does not work ;)

Comment: This does not answer the OP, where is specifically does NOT want to assume directory for output, something the /I switch does. Plus, the answer is formulated in a snide manner.

Comment: Even when `/I` is present, this prompt still appears when copying one file... I don't really get why there are so many upvotes here...

Answer (score 27):

So, there is a simple fix for this.  It is admittedly awkward, but it works.
xcopy will not prompt to find out if the destination is a directory or file IF the new file(filename) already exists.  If you precede your xcopy command with a simple echo to the new filename, it will overwrite the empty file.  Example

```
echo.>newfile.txt
xcopy oldfile.txt newfile.txt /Y
```

Comment: This won't copy file attributes :-( If you need no attrs then isn't `copy` better?

Answer (score 7):

I met same issue when try to copy file with new name only if file does not exist in destination or exist (with new name), but is older. The solution is to add `*` char at end of destination file name. Example:

```
xcopy "C:\src\whee.config.txt" "C:\dest\bee.config.txt*" /D /Y
```

Answer (score 4):

This is from Bills answer.

Just to be really clear for others.

If you are copying **ONE** file from one place to another **AND** you want the full directory structure to be created, use the following command:

```
xcopy "C:\Data\Images\2013\08\12\85e4a707-2672-481b-92fb-67ecff20c96b.jpg" "C:\Target Data\\Images\2013\08\12\85e4a707-2672-481b-92fb-67ecff20c96b.jpg\"
```

Yes, put a backslash at the end of the file name and **it will NOT ask you if it's a file or directory.** Because there is only ONE file in the source, it will assume it's a file.

Comment: This is wrong. When running "xcopy versionBase.txt asd\versionBase.txt\" and the asd directory is not present, I get the asd\versionBase.txt\versionBase.txt file.

Comment: As with other answers on this page, this post is not addressing the original question.  The question was how to copy AND rename (in one step) a file.   As with other apparently confused answers, this talks about how to copy the file WITHOUT renaming.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that it really creates a **directory** with that name, not a folder. Test it out, and run a dir afterwards, and you will see something like this:

`dir "C:\Target Data\\Images\2013\08\12"`

`09/25/2015  10:48 AM    <DIR>          85e4a707-2672-481b-92fb-67ecff20c96b.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

XCOPY with * at the end of the target to copy files whether they exist or not in destination
XCOPY with \ at the end of the target to copy folders and contents whether exist or not in destination

Alternatively

RoboForm SOURCE DEST FILE for files
RoboForm SOURCE DEST for folders

Answer (score 2):

`xcopy src dest /I`

`REM This assumes dest is a folder and will create it, if it doesnt exists`

Comment: This still prompts when copying single file

Answer (score 2):

Back to the original question:

```
 xcopy "bin\development\whee.config.example" "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config"
```

could be done with two commands eg:

```
mkdir "c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config\.."
xcopy "bin\development\whee.config.example" "c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config\"
```

By simply appending "\.." to the path of the destination file the destination directory is created if it not already exists. In this case

```
"c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\"
```

which is the parent directory of
the non-existing directory

```
"c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config\.."
```

At least for WIN7 **mkdir** does not care if the directory

```
"c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config\"
```

really exists.

Comment: An interesting fix if the directory does not exist. Unfortunately, the next line (in my testing) still prompts the user.

Comment: You're right it shoud be 

    xcopy "bin\development\whee.config.example" "c:\mybackup\TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config\".
I used my aproach to copy files to a dirotory that might not exist. For renaming it looks like a backslash has to be added at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and both robocopy and xcopy did not help, as I wanted to suppress the comments and use a different destination filename. I found

```
type filename.txt > destfolder\destfilename.txt
```

working as per my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do if you wanna copy just file and change it's name at destination is :

> xcopy /f /y "bin\development\example.exe"
>   "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\NewName.exe*"

And it's Gonna work fine

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `robocopy` instead of `copy` or `xcopy`.  Used as command or in GUI on clients or servers.  Tolerant of network pauses and you can choose to ignore file attributes when copying of copy by file attributes.  Oh, and it supports multi-core machines so files are copied much faster in "parallel" with each other instead of sequentially.  `robocopy` can be found on MS TechNet.

Comment: I use robocopy all the time. However, for this poster's question, it will not work, as it cannot rename files.  Something I didn't know before today is that **xcopy** does have a /z switch, which is tolerant of network pauses!

Answer (score 1):

For duplicating large files, xopy with /J switch is a good choice. In this case, simply pipe an F for file or a D for directory. Also, you can save jobs in an array for future references. For example:

```
$MyScriptBlock = {
    Param ($SOURCE, $DESTINATION) 
    'F' | XCOPY $SOURCE $DESTINATION /J/Y 
    #DESTINATION IS FILE, COPY WITHOUT PROMPT IN DIRECT BUFFER MODE
}
JOBS +=START-JOB -SCRIPTBLOCK $MyScriptBlock -ARGUMENTLIST $SOURCE,$DESTIBNATION
$JOBS | WAIT-JOB | REMOVE-JOB
```

Thanks to Chand with a bit modifications: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/users/3705330/chand

Answer (score 1):

Place an asterisk(*) at the end of the destination path to skip the dispute of D and F.

Example:

> xcopy "compressedOutput.xml" "../../Execute
>   Scripts/APIAutomation/Libraries/rerunlastfailedbuild.xml*"

Answer (score 0):

Use copy instead of xcopy when copying files.

e.g.
  copy "bin\development\whee.config.example"
          "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\whee.config"

Comment: I am trying to copy a file to the same folder with a different name and xcopy cannot work. I use `copy /Y source destination` to pass the overwrite confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Work Around, use ReName... and Name it some Cryptic Name, then ReName it to its Proper Name

C:

CD "C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Web Sites\AngelFire~Zoe\"

XCopy /D /I /V /Y  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Web Sites\HostGator ~ ZoeBeans\cop.htm"

Ren "cop.htm" "christ-our-passover.htm"

Answer (score 0):

xcopy will allow you to copy a single file into a specifed folder it just wont allow you to define a destination name. If you require the destination name just rename it before you copy it.

ren "bin\development\whee.config.example" whee.config

xcopy /R/Y "bin\development\whee.config"
          "TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\"

Comment: Assuming this would work in a particular environment (i.e., there's certain to never be a whee.config in the source folder), to replicate the OP's code, shouldn't it include a rename back to the original name?
`ren "bin\development\whee.config" whee.config.example`

Answer (score 0):

When working with **single files** , I use both commands.

To copy a file to another **existing** directory, use `copy`

```
copy srcPath\srcFile existingDir\newFile
```

To copy an existing file to **and** create new directories, use `xcopy`

```
xcopy srcPath\srcFile newDirectoryPath\newFile
```

To suppress the `xcopy` 'file or directory' prompt, echo in the response. So for a file copy echo in `f`.

```
echo f | xcopy srcPath\srcFile newDirectoryPath\newFile
```

Note flag `/y` works in both commands to suppress the confirmation to overwrite the existing destination file.

---

MS Docs: [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy), [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 11 22H2 (or around that build) MS added the /-I switch to automate the "F = file" answer.
This is what the OP rightfully expected to exist all those years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're not actually changing the filename, you can take out the filename from the destination and there will be no questions.

```
xcopy bin\development\whee.config.example TestConnectionExternal\bin\Debug\  /Y
```

This approach works well when the destination directory is guaranteed to exist, and when the source may equally be a file or directory.

Comment: @downvoters: Why this answer could have been downvoted?  In this context, the `Debug` directory is probably guaranteed to exist.

Comment: This response says "since you're not actually changing the filename", whereas the original question clearly said "copy a file from one directory to another AND RENAME IT in the destination directory".   So this seems irrelevant to the topic.

Answer (score -2):

Does xxxxxxxxxxxx specify a file name
or directory name on the target

```
(F = file, D = directory)? D

if a File : (echo F)
if a Directory (echo D)
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot specify that it's always a file. If you don't need xcopy's other features, why not just use regular `copy`?

Comment: One reason is that `copy`, being an internal command, doesn't set ErrorLevel.  If you want to be able to influence the path of a batch file if a copy error occurs, you need to use `XCOPY`.

Comment: Another reason is if you want to use other features of xcopy, like /d