# How to overwrite existing files in batch?

Tags: batch-file, overwrite

The following command copies and moves a file but I also need it to overwrite the file it's replacing.

```
xcopy /s c:\mmyinbox\test.doc C:\myoutbox
```

Comment: According to here https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html#:~:text=XCOPY%20is%20similar%20to%20the,source%20and%20destination%20in%20detail.&text=%2FD%3Amm%2Ddd%2D,newer%20than%20the%20destination%20time.XCOPY `xcopy` has been deprecated. Although it's still ships - `robocopy` is the successor.

Answer (score 176):

Add /Y to the command line

Comment: How to submit F = File , D = directory ?

Comment: @YumYumYum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018289/xcopy-file-rename-suppress-does-xxx-specify-a-file-name-message

Comment: xcopy /s/Y c:\mmyinbox\test.doc C:\myoutbox
(Y is a CAPITAL.)

Answer (score 47):

You can use :

```
copy /b/v/y
```

See [SS64 on COPY](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html).

Comment: im new to batch whats b/v/y stand for?

Comment: use `copy /?` to have help! `/b` means binary file, `/v` means check, `/y` is force. http://www.ss64.com is a very good reference otherwise.

Comment: sorry i just realised i have spaces in my foldernames i ussually use underscores, How is this handld properly?

Comment: enclose your arguments inside `"`'s. If you have a `"` inside an argument which is enclosed (which is never the case for filenames) double it.

Comment: @Mal also you can do `dir /X` in folder above to get the directory name with a `~` in it  instead. The you don't need the quotes if you use that abridged variant. Source: https://superuser.com/questions/179449/windows-path-without-spaces-with-1

Answer (score 37):

Add `/y` to the command line of `xcopy`:

Example:

```
xcopy /y c:\mmyinbox\test.doc C:\myoutbox
```

Comment: Is there any more information you can add that isn't already in another answer? This doesn't really need to be posted as a new answer otherwise.

Comment: use a trailing slash for the target path, otherwise it will give error if target folder doesnt exist

Comment: @Michelle the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051313/2076973) is a boomer response that doesn't give the full command that we need to execute. This is a chad answer that you can just copy and paste, the best answer

Answer (score 24):

you need to simply add /Y

```
xcopy /s c:\mmyinbox\test.doc C:\myoutbox /Y
```

and if you're using path with spaces, try this

```
xcopy /s "c:\mmyinbox\test.doc" "C:\myoutbox" /Y
```

Comment: Is there any more information you can add that isn't already in another answer? This doesn't really need to be posted as a new answer otherwise

Answer (score 19):

For copying one file to another directory overwriting without any prompt i ended up using the simply COPY command:

```
copy /Y ".\mySourceFile.txt" "..\target\myDestinationFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 14):

If the copy command is run from within a batch job you do not need to use the /Y switch: it will overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 3):

A command that would copy in any case

```
xcopy "path\source" "path\destination" /s/h/e/k/f/c/y
```

Answer (score 1):

If destination file is read only use `/y/r`

```
xcopy /y/r source.txt dest.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me to copy and overwrite a file from B:\ to Z:\ drive in a batch script.

```
echo F| XCOPY B:\utils\MyFile.txt Z:\Backup\CopyFile.txt /Y
```

The "/Y" parameter at the end overwrites the destination file, if it exists.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer **Windows command prompt** help using following command : `xcopy /?`