# XCOPY: Overwrite all without prompt in BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I'm writing a batch program for copying all files *newer than the destination* from "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop" to "D:\Backup".

This code is works:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\*.*" "D:\Backup\" /K /D /H
```

However, it asks for each existing destination file: `Overwrite file [Yes / No / All]?`

I want to **overwrite** all existing destination files **without** user intervention.

How can I solve this?

Comment: use `/Y` option.

Comment: Type `XCOPY/?` at the Command prompt, hit enter and read the help information on the command. _Or better yet, try it with `ROBOCOPY/?` which superseded `XCOPY` way back when Windows Vista came out!_

Comment: @Compo: Just as a personal comment: it is not easy to start to use `ROBOCOPY` if the users are not computer oriented (i.e. if they can't find the `/Y` switch from `xcopy` help screen). There are several complex details there...

Comment: @Aacini, If a user isn't computer orientated, it would be foolhardy to even consider the command line, _(there are many GUI methods for backing up files and directories)_. Choosing the command line route a decision was made to use a depracated command even over `Copy` and include some of its options. This reasonably implies an ability to read and understand command help output.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `/Y`, its good!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite existing files in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051294/how-to-overwrite-existing-files-in-batch)

Comment: /y help me, thanks

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The solution is the `/Y` switch:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\*.*" "D:\Backup\" /K /D /H /Y
```

Comment: the /Y option only overwrites the pre-existing files: https://www.lifewire.com/xcopy-command-2618103

Comment: In my case, I am looking to overwrite EVERYTHING. the contents of one folder to replace another folder's content

Comment: I know, stupid windows. each one of them has a different problem. rmdir says folder is in use by another applicaion, Poweshell Remove-Item says dies not have permission and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to copy some backups from a share location (or server) to a local one by replace option, so I use this code and it worked well:

```
Xcopy "\\bi-srv\SQL\Backup" "E:\backup\sql\Backup" /c /i /e /h /y
```

just save it in a bat format and schedule it by windows task scheduler