# I want to copy a directory excluding one file

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I have used the xcopy command with /EXCLUDE switch but for that i have to make another file that contains the list of files to be excluded.
Below is the xcopy command i am using...

```
xcopy /EXCLUDE:C:\AA\excludedfiles.txt C:\AA d:\Models\Broker\NB\MOTNB0056 
/S /E
```

where excludedfiles.txt contains the name of file that i want to exclude.
C:\AA is source and d:\Models\Broker\NB\MOTNB0056  is destination.

However i don't want to make extra file(excludedfiles.txt) for it. Suggest a command that exclude a file by giving just its path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) is deprecated. It has been replaced by [ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Open a command prompt window an run `robocopy /?` for help on command **ROBOCOPY**.
The help of **XCOPY** is output on running `xcopy /?` in the command prompt window.

The Windows command [ROBOCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) has the option `/XF` to exclude one or more files specified after this switch and it is even possible to use wildcards.

The command to use is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe C:\AA D:\Models\Broker\NB\MOTNB0056 /E /XF C:\AA\FileToExclude.ext
```

Some additional notes:

`/S` means copying with subdirectories, but **without empty** directories.
`/E` means copying with subdirectories **with including empty** directories.

It does not make much sense to specify both on the command line.

It is advisable to specify the target directory with backslash at the end on using **XCOPY**. That makes it clear for **XCOPY** that the target string specifies a directory and not a file. **XCOPY** supports also copying a single file to a new destination with a new file name. The backslash at the end of the destination directory path on using **XCOPY** is important in case of just a single file is copied as it can be read in the answer on [batch file asks for file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829012/3074564).

It is **not** advisable to let any directory path end with a backslash on using **ROBOCOPY**, especially if the directory path must be enclosed in `"` because of containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. **ROBOCOPY** interprets a backslash left to `"` or one more `\` as escape character for `"` respectively `\`. That special command line arguments parsing behavior of **ROBOCOPY** is counterproductive for source / destination path on being enclosed in `"` and the directory paths end with the directory separator `\`. Directory paths on **ROBOCOPY** command line end best never with `\`, except a directory path references the root directory of a drive. The backslash at the end is required in this special use case on which just `C:\`,  `N:\`, ... without `"` should be used on the **ROBOCOPY** command line.

Both commands create the entire directory tree to target directory if this is necessary.

See Microsoft's documentation on [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/) on searching for a command for a specific file operation from command line or batch file.

Comment: But there is a issue with using ROBOCOPY as it gives exit code 1 when One or more files were copied successfully.Now what if it copies some files but skips one or more file accidently or due to any fault.Then also it will throw exit code 1. Is there a solution to fix it?....@Mofi

Comment: @rohit.dagur The link to  SS64's [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) page in my answer contains a link to [Robocopy Exit Codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) explaining in detail with which values __ROBOCOPY__ exits. If you want to test on any failure during copying in your batch file use as next command `if errorlevel 8 goto FileCopyError`. Please study also Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) explaining why it is enough to use `if errorlevel 8` to jump to the label on any copy error.