# How to add time stamp to log lines in log file from batch file output?

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, logfile

I want to add time stamp to log lines from batch output.

Here is my batch file:

```
@Echo off
SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0

:Logit
set "affix=%date%_%time%"
set "affix=%affix::=%"
set "affix=%affix:/=%"
xcopy "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_%affix%.xlsx"*
```

Output of log file:

```
I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
1 File(s) copied
```

I want output log file looking like this:

```
I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
20180831_124500 : 1 File(s) copied
```

How could this be achieved?

Some more information:

1. The asterisk at end of target argument string is required for copying the file without prompt. There would be a prompt asking if target is a file or a directory if `*` would not be used at end of target file name.
2. `xcopy` is used because copied is a file from a network drive to local drive.

The output result is as below after running the batch file:

```
I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
08312018_163959.07 :I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
1 File(s) copied
```

May it be as below?

```
I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
08312018_163959.07  1 File(s) copied
```

So the region dependent date format is `MM/DD/YYY` and time format is `HH:mm:ss.ms`.

Comment: right below the very last line, put this line `echo %affix%` that will still set everything as you wanted copy the file, but simply when the label is called, it will echo the modified time and date to the logfile after the file copy..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo| set /p=%affix%` to eliminate the newline at echo time as:

```
@Echo off
SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0
:Logit
set "affix=%date%_%time%"
set "affix=%affix::=%"
set "affix=%affix:/=%"
echo|set /p=%affix% :
xcopy "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_%affix%.xlsx"*
```

**Result:**

```
I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
2018-08-31_124900 :        1 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: @v1787v. This is the best I can do, I removed the file echo as it was a test, but your result cannot come differently than this, you cannot split the output of the command by default, they only possible way would be to create a for loop, pipe the command to nul, then use the output and split that into a variable and echo to file. but that seems really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You're only `XCopy`ing one file, so you know that your last line of output on success will be the language dependent string `1 File(s) copied`.
As you've already limited the script to using a locale dependent `%DATE%` and `%TIME%`, I have assumed that language dependency for this task is fine.

Here therefore is a ridiculous looking example script:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "srcfile=I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx"
Set "destdir=D:\TL\BACKUP"
Set "logfile=MyLogFile.log"

For %%A In ("%srcfile%") Do Set "dstname=%%~nA" & Set "destext=%%~xA"

For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=|" %%A In ('
    Echo F^|XCopy "%srcfile%" "|%DATE:/=%_%TIME::=%|" /L 2^>Nul ^&^
    Echo F^|Xcopy "%srcfile%" "%destdir%\%dstname%_%DATE:/=%_%TIME::=%%destext%" /Y ^>Nul 2^>^&1
') Do (If Not "%%B"=="" Set "_=%%B"
    If Defined _ If /I "%%A"=="%srcfile%" ((
            Echo %%A&Call Echo %%_%%  1 File(s^) copied)>"%logfile%"))
```

*You should change nothing other than the values for the variables on lines **`2`**-**`4`**.
However should you be using an existing logfile, you may wish to change **`>`** on the last line to **`>>`***

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following code producing exactly the initially wanted output in log file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log"
del "%LOGFILE%" 2>nul
call :Logit >>"%LOGFILE%"
endlocal
exit /B 0

:Logit
set "FileDate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%"
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_%FileDate%.xlsx*" /C /V /Y 2^>nul') do (
    if not "%%J" == "" (
        echo %%I:%%J
    ) else (
        echo %FileDate% : %%I
    )
)
goto :EOF
```

The region dependent date and time is reformatted to `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` by using string substitutions of the dynamic environment variables `DATE` and `TIME` as explained in detail for example by the answer on the question: [What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236739/3074564) For a much slower, but region independent solution, to get date/time in a specific format see for example the answer on: [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564)

The current date and time in format `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` is assigned to the environment variable `FileDate` used twice on the next line, once in name of target file and once more in output of last line of reformatted output of command **XCOPY**.

The **XCOPY** command line used here is for example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_20180831_163959.xlsx*" /C /R /V /Y 2>nul
```

This command line is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process started by **FOR** with `cmd.exe /C` in background. **FOR** captures all lines written to handle **STDOUT** of this command process before processing the captured lines.

**XCOPY** outputs to handle **STDOUT** the names of the copied files with full path and as last line a summary information. Errors on file copying are written to handle **STDERR** which are suppressed by redirecting them to device **NUL**.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `xcopy` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The asterisk `*` at end of target file name should be within the double quotes of second argument string and not outside because otherwise `cmd.exe` respectively `xcopy.exe` has to correct this wrong syntax.

Please note that the trick with `*` at end of target file name works here by chance because source and target file have same file extension and the source file name is always shorter than the target file name. Otherwise the command would fail or target file gets an unwanted name being a concatenation of target file name + the characters of source file name after n characters of target file name.

In general there are better methods to avoid a halt on prompt which **XCOPY** requests in case of a single file is copied with a new file name. The letter to answer the prompt can be output first to **STDOUT** redirected to handle **STDIN** of **XCOPY** command as demonstrated language independent in answer on [batch file asks for file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829012/3074564).

The captured output of **XCOPY** is processed by **FOR** line by line with skipping empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon `;` as being the default end of line character of option `eol=` not used here.

The goal here is to output all lines with a full qualified file output by **XCOPY** in background command process also in this command process, but output the last line with the summary information different by prepending it with the date/time in wanted format, a space, a colon and one more space.

For that reason the default line splitting behavior on spaces/tabs with assigning only first substring (token) to specified loop variable `I` is modified here by the options `tokens=1* delims=:`. **FOR** splits up a line on colons now.

Only the lines with a full qualified file name starting with a drive letter and a colon contain a colon at all. On such lines the drive letter is assigned to specified loop variable `I` as specified by `tokens=1`. The rest of a file name line after first colon is assigned without any further splitting to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to loop variable `J` which is here everything after the colon after drive letter.

The summary information line does not contain a colon. For that reason **FOR** assigns the entire summary information to loop variable `I` and `J` holds an empty string.

The loop variable `J` is never empty on a line with a file name starting with a drive letter and a colon. This fact is used here to determine if the line from **XCOPY** should be output as is with inserting the removed colon between drive letter and file path + file name + file extension or output the summary information with date/time at beginning.

Please note that this method works only on copying files from a drive with a drive letter. A different method would be necessary for source files with a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention) path.

In fact copying a single file can be done much easier with command **COPY** instead of **XCOPY** even from/to a network drive or when source/target file name is specified with a UNC path. **COPY** has also the options `/V` and `/Y` and even `/Z` like **XCOPY**. **COPY** does not create the target directory structure like **XCOPY**, but this can be done with command **MD** before. **COPY** can't overwrite a read-only file as **XCOPY** can do on using option `/R`, but this limitation of **COPY** is most likely not relevant here. And **COPY** does not copy a file with hidden attribute set. However, in general copying a single file is nevertheless best done with command **COPY** instead of **XCOPY**.

So here is one more solution with using command **COPY** which is faster than the **XCOPY** solution as there is no reason for executing the file copy in a separate command process, capture any line, split them and output them concatenated again or modified.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log"
md "D:\TL\BACKUP" 2>nul
del "%LOGFILE%" 2>nul
call :Logit >>"%LOGFILE%"
endlocal
exit /B 0

:Logit
set "FileDate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%"
echo I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
copy /B /V /Y "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_%FileDate%.xlsx" >nul 2>nul && echo %FileDate% : 1 File(s) copied|| echo %FileDate% : 0 File(s) copied
goto :EOF
```

This solution has also the advantage that the line output on success or error can be fully customized. **COPY** exits with a value greater 0 on an error like source file not available or target file/directory is write-protected currently or permanently.

Example of a better output for a single copied file on success or error (subroutine only):

```
:Logit
set "FileDate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%"
copy /B /V /Y "I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx" "D:\TL\BACKUP\Data_%FileDate%.xlsx" >nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo %FileDate% : Copied successfully I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
) else (
    echo %FileDate% : Failed to copy file I:\DF\AB\Data.xlsx
)
goto :EOF
```

It is of course also possible to use the command line

```
set "FileDate=%DATE:/=%_%TIME::=%"
```

in the batch file to get the date and time in format `MMddyyyy_HHmmss.ms` if that is really wanted now. I don't recommend this date/time format as it is not good on alphabetical list of all `Data_*.xlsx` files in directory `D:\TL\BACKUP`. The list of files sorted by name is with the date/time format `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` automatically also sorted by date/time.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operators `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Thanks you so much Mofi

Answer (score 0):

`powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get- 
Date)).TotalSeconds">LOG.TXT`

Although this is not the format you suggested, this format is called `epoch time`.

The good thing about this format is that it is always a float value.

`LOG.TXT` will be the name of the log, make sure you are in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks you so much Benjamin2002