# what does echo modifiers "f|" do in bat file

Tags: batch-file, echo, modifier

What does "f|" do in this bat command

```
echo f|xcopy /Y /v "foo.exe" "%TargetFile1%"
```

Comment: I recommend to read my long answer on [Why does the command XCOPY in batch file ask for file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829012/3074564) The simple solution would be using in this case the internal command __COPY__ of `cmd.exe` although it is not posted with which value the environment variable `TargetFile1` is defined in the batch file. That would be much better and faster.

Comment: It is very inefficient letting `cmd.exe` first search in current directory and next in the directories of local environment variable `PATH` for a file with name `xcopy` with no file extension or with a file extension listed in local environment variable `PATHEXT` for finding hopefully `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe` and execute this executable deprecated since Microsoft released Windows Vista for copying a single file from the current working directory to the destination directory if the destination directory exists already.

Comment: Thanks mofi - since I was just interested in the "f|" function I did not include the TargetFile1 definition. Sorry for the confusion - and I did read your great Why....

Answer (score 0):

`f|` are not modifiers; `f` is what `echo` sends to standard output, and `|` is a pipe, which redirects the standard output of `echo` to the standard input of `xcopy`. What effect this has is unclear and may be none at all; I can't find anything that suggests that `xcopy` prompts for anything from standard input.

Comment: thanks Jeff This is what happens if I leave it out -- it won't change the RO attribute of the file it is suppose to overwrite

Comment: -- it may not even be overwriting it --  without the echo, just xcopy, it does change it

Comment: I guess I don't really need the echo as it adds nothing to the output. I think it was someones suggestion, but I don't understand why now. It has been a while.