# Suppress bat file automated input

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the command `echo f | xcopy /f /y srcfile destfile` as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018289/xcopy-file-rename-suppress-does-xxx-specify-a-file-name-message), and it works great, but it still shows up.
I've tried prepending `1>nul` and `2>nul` to completely suppress it, but that had undesired results.  I do need to use xcopy and I do need to specify the target filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
@echo off
echo f | xcopy /f /y srcfile destfile >nul
```