# DOS xcopy command to move files that have been restored ending with (1)

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

In error, I restored a large amount of files, and selected if the file exists restore with a different file name. All the files restored end in (1) . For example  test.pdf would be restored as test(1).pdf.  The result is two identical files with different names

Is there a XCOPY command or other DOS command that will search the drive and its subfolders for file names that end in (1),  and move those files into a temp folder.  If so, it would be greatly appreciated if you could give me the command line info

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcopy file, rename, suppress "Does xxx specify a file name..." message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018289/xcopy-file-rename-suppress-does-xxx-specify-a-file-name-message)

Comment: Does it really need to be a 16-bit DOS command?  If you're using Windows, you could open a Windows Explorer window, search your drive for all files named `*(1).*`, and then drag the search results wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "*(*)*" ^| findstr "([0-9][0-9]*)\."') do ECHO MOVE "%%~fa" "c:\temp"
```

It searches *recursively* in the start folder and all subfolders and moves `"([0-9][0-9]*)\."` files to `c:\temp`. Look at the output and remove `ECHO` if it looks good.