# How to suppress user input for xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a batch file that copies the file from one directory to other.
Below is my command.

```
xcopy  /y /e /s /c help_vc8.txt ..\..\help_vc8.txt.
```

When I run the batch file it asks for user input in CMD and displays below message:

```
Does ..\..\help_vc8.txt 
specify a file name  or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

Now user has to enter f or d. I do not want this message and user should not enter f or d. Everything should happen on its own.
Please help me if I missed out any thing in the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018289/xcopy-file-rename-suppress-does-xxx-specify-a-file-name-message

Comment: If you don't rename the file you can omit the file name and specify only the target directory.

Comment: I recommend that you avoid `xcopy`.  Try either plain old `copy` or `robocopy` instead, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo f|xcopy /y /e /s /c help_vc8.txt ....\help_vc8.txt
```

try like this for file.

```
echo D|xcopy /y /e /s /c help_vc8.txt ....\help_vc8.txt
```

for directory.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the name of the destination directory.

if it really is `\help_vc8.txt`  write it as `\help_vc8.txt\` with the trailing `\` and then xcopy will know it's  supposed to be a directory,

or maybe you want: `xcopy  /y /e /s /c help_vc8.txt ..\..\`

Comment: Thanks for response but in my case it is file and the solution you suggested works well wit the directory. But what needs to be done for files.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now!