# XCOPY still asking (F = file, D = directory) confirmation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

My batch script `xcopy` is still asking `F = file, D = directory` confirmation even though I have added `/F` in the script, the log is showing as below.
Please help on how to avoid asking confirmation.

Script:

```
net use p: /delete  
net use p: "\\200clan\F_Drive" /USER:adm /PERSISTENT:NO-1111
set source=%1
set target=p:/%2

echo %source% %target%

xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
```

Log:

> ```
> C:\test\foldera>xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "C:/test/folder1/folder2/logs/154/compareReport_177.html" "p:/Services/WSDLCompare/177_20151116/compareReport_177.html"
> Does P:\Services\WSDLCompare\177_20151116\UIReport_177.html specify a file name
> or directory name on the target
> (F = file, D = directory)?
> ```

Comment: In case you don't bother to go through all the details and options of `xcopy` add  a [back-slash](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1126822) at the end of your target path `%target\%`

Comment: @mchar, but then you have to move it one place beack like `%target%\ `(so behind the closing `%`)...

Answer (score 133):

The `/I` switch (not `/F` as you mentioned in your question) prevents `xcopy` from asking whether the destination is a file or a directory only if multiple source files are given, so if the source is a directory, or if wildcards `?` or `*` are used. If the destination already exists, such prompt does never appear.

There are the following scenarios (depending on the provided values of `%source%` and `%target%`):

- **a single source file, the destination is a file:**

  the `/I` switch is useless, so you need to pipe `F` into the `xcopy` command line:

  ```
  echo F|xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

  provided that the `/Y` switch is given (to force overwriting), you could also create the target file in advance (empty file):

  ```
  >> "%target%" rem/
  xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```
- **a single source file, the destination is a directory:**

  the `/I` switch is useless too; you can pipe `D` into the `xcopy` command line:

  ```
  echo D|xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

  or you can simply append a `\` to the destination:

  ```
  xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%\"
  ```

  although this causes trouble when `%target%` specifies the current directory of a drive like `D:` for instance, because `D:` means the current directory of this drive whereas `D:\` means the root directory of it;

  or you create the destination directory in advance:

  ```
  2> nul mkdir "%target%"
  xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

  the `2> nul` portion suppresses the error message in case the directory already exists;
- **multiple source files, the destination is a file:**

  this is usually a senseless situation, because you tell `xcopy` to copy each source file to the same destination file, thus attempting to overwrite it;
- **multiple source files, the destination is a directory:**

  the `/I` switch makes sense here:

  ```
  xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

  the pipe option also works here:

  ```
  echo D|xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

  so does appending a `\` to the destination (regarding the limitation as mentioned above):

  ```
  xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%\"
  ```

  or you create the destination directory in advance:

  ```
  2> nul mkdir "%target%"
  xcopy /S /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
  ```

#### Conclusion

The most flexible and secure solution is to pipe the desired selection (`F` or `D`) into the `xcopy` command line. (Note that the query is locale-dependent.)

---

#### Supplement

There are some minor issues in your code fragment I want to mention here:

- you should generally use the `\` as a path separator as this is the Windows standard character for that purpose (although `/` works too in most cases);
- there is `-1111` appended to your second `net use` command line; if this constitutes the password for the resource, it should be moved before the `/USER` option; otherwise just remove it;
- your `set` command lines introduce problems with some special characters (like `&`, `^`, `(`, `)`); to avoid such, state `set "source=%~1"` and `set "target=p:/%~2"`; the `~` removes potential surrounding `""` from the arguments (which are required if they contain <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`);

Here is the code with the all of the above things reworked:

```
net use P: /DELETE
rem supposing `-1111` constitutes the password for the resource:
net use P: "\\200clan\F_Drive" -1111 /USER:adm /PERSISTENT:NO

set "source=%~1"
set "target=P:\%~2"

echo "%source%" "%target%"

rem supposing the destination is a directory:
echo D|xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"


rem actually you do not need any interim variables:
REM echo D|xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%~1" "P:\%~2"
```

Comment: Very good answer. I just want to add that `F` for __file__ and `D` for __directory__ are only the right characters on English Windows. For example on a German Windows `D` is for a file (German: Datei)  and `V` is for a directory (German: Verzeichnis). If an OS language independent solution is needed for copying a single file with `xcopy` which can't be copied with `copy`, look on batch code on [this answer on BATCH file asks for file or folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35829012/3074564).

Comment: Adding the slash to the end of the target directory fixed it for me.  It no longer asks if the path is a file or directory.  Thanks!

Comment: My Solution was simple:  Replace XCOPY for COPY command, ejem:  COPY "%source%" "%target%" /Y

Comment: Sure, @Jhollman, `copy` doesn't prompt for file/dir.; it has way less options though, so it might not be adequate for some situations…

Comment: Very good answer. But be aware there is a localization issue with that - it works for englisch Windows versions, but for example on a German Windows it will be "d = file (datei), v = directory (verzeichnis)", so you would write `echo d | xcopy 23.txt 24.txt` instead.

Comment: Tip: When trying to copy a file from inside a vb-script using wscript, then "copy" and "echo" does not work as they are not .exe or .com files but built into the system. The solution above to first create an empty file and adding the /Y works. Create an empty file with filesystemobject, ex. fs.createtextfile and then close it immediately.

Comment: Well, @Sourcery, to use `copy` from VBScript, `cmd.exe /D /C copy` could be used, although I would prefer to use VBScript's internal functions to copy files rather than leveraging `cmd.exe`…

Answer (score 94):

Put a `\` behind the target to suppress the question and specify it as a folder:

```
xcopy src dest\
```

Put a `*` behind the target to suppress the question and specify it as a file:

```
xcopy src dest*
```

**Note:** The second command is a *hack* that relies on wildcard matching (will match any item starting with "dest") so use it at your own risk!

Comment: I keep seeing this as a suggestion and I have to say after testing it, it doesn't work as advertised. The wildcard (*) is still a wildcard so it will try to match anything that starts with file2 (using the same example above). I recommend using the piping method instead which is kind of silly, but it works. I wish that there was a switch that just said "It's always a file" or "It's always a directory".

Answer (score 20):

`xcopy` doesn't know the target is a directory. You clarify this by putting a backslash at the end:

```
xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%\"
```

Comment: This helped my situation, even though it is technically not the correct answer for the original post. The example target variable included the full path plus filename, so adding a backslash at the end will only confuse things for the original poster. If the `source` is a _single file_ and the `target` is a _folder_, as it is in my case, adding the backslash to the target and using the `/i` switch made the File/Directory question go away and the directory was then correctly presumed.

Answer (score 13):

When copying a single file with XCOPY, there is no option to indicate if the destination is a filename or a directory (with the filename defaulting to that of the source file).
In such cases XCOPY will prompt with a (locale specific) message like:

C:> xcopy foo.txt bar.txt

it prompts 
**Does foo.txt specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?**

Adding a wildcard (*) to the end of the destination will suppress this prompt and default to copying as a file:

C:> xcopy foo.txt bar.txt*
1 File(s) copied

This requires the source and target file extensions to be the same length, typically 3 characters.

for more information: https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Answer (score -1):

Removing the destination filename will suppress the message. This works for me!

Answer (score -1):

I use:

```
xcopy /S /I /Q /Y /F "%source%" "%target%"
```

It works.

Comment: The help (xcopy /?) shows that /Q and /F are opposites: /Q: Does not display file names while copying; /F: Displays full source and destination file names while copying.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo F>xcopy_answer.tmp
xcopy xcopy /Q/Y "%source%" "%target%"<xcopy_answer.tmp
```