# Batch command XCOPY prompts me: Is the destination file or directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I run this file:

```
xcopy .\*.odt .\source.zip
```

I am prompted to specify what source.zip is:

```
xcopy .\*.odt .\source.zip
Does .\source.zip specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

In my case when it find the `.odt` file to copy the file and place in the same directory but with new name **source.zip**. Is there approach to avoid the prompting since I always want destination to be a file not directory.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to copy a bunch of files into one file? In case you're trying to add all those files to one zipfile, `xcopy` is not the way to do it.

Comment: No, there will be only one file with extention `.odt`. I want ot copy it into the same directory with the new name _source.zip_. Since the the .odt may have any name I want it with different name but to keep the original.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use `xcopy` for renaming a file: you can use `xcopy` for copying bunches of files, but when you need to rename a file, you need the `copy` command.

Comment: Whne I use `copy .\*.odt .\source.zip`  the .zip is corrupted. But when I use: `copy .\*.odt .\*.zip` everything is fine, but the name of the `zip` is same as the name of the `odt` which is not desired in my case

Comment: The problem is that you try to do everything within one single command. I'd propose you to search for the name of the *.odt file, put that filename into a variable, and then copy that filename into source.zip.

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow, I am confused as to why you are not using the `RENAME` command?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33770152/5047996); you can use `echo F|xcopy .\*.odt .\source.zip`, if, and _only_ if, `*.odt` matches a single file!

Answer (score 0):

Any `.odt` file (being in `.zip` format in fact) is a *binary file*, see [OpenDocument **Document Representation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification)

> - As a collection of several sub-documents within a package, each of which stores part of the complete document. This is the common
>     representation of OpenDocument documents. It uses filename extensions
>     such as `.odt`, `.ott`, `.ods`, `.odp` ... etc. The package is a
>     standard `ZIP` file with different filename extensions and with a
>     defined structure of sub-documents. Each sub-document within a package
>     has a different document root and stores a particular aspect of the
>     `XML` document. All types of documents (e.g. text and spreadsheet
>     documents) use the same set of document and sub-document definitions.

Therefore, you need to *treat* it as a *binary file* (read `copy /?`):

```
copy /B .\*.odt .\source.zip
```

Above command would work smoothly only if  there will be only one file with extension `.odt`. Otherwise, it will prompt you for `Overwrite .\source.zip? (Yes/No/All):`. To stay on the safe side:

- from command line `for %G in (.\*.odt) do copy /B "%G" ".\source_%~nG.zip"`
- from a batch script `for %%G in (.\*.odt) do copy /B "%%G" ".\source_%%~nG.zip"`

`%~nG` (or in batch `%%~nG`) explanation: read [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: the `/B` flag is not needed in this case. just `copy *.old source.zip` will work