# Renaming a file after it has been copied using batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I have the following code that copies certain files from one folder into another. I want to name the copied file to 'Customer Dets'. I want to do it in the same batch file if possible.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%V IN ("%DATE%") DO SET TDY=%%V   
xcopy  /y "C:\Users\rnan\Desktop\Batch Files\KGP\FileHistory\*Customer*" "C:\Users\rnan\Desktop\Batch Files\*.*" /d:%TDY%     
SET TDY=
```

Comment: if you rename your files to a static name, won't you overwrite the file at every iteration of your loop?

Comment: @blaze_125 That is the plan. Its the end of the day file, so everyday i want to replace the existing file with a new file with the same name.

Comment: @blaze_125 There is no loop here. The for loop is for storing the date in TDY variable.

Comment: My bad. Something like this should work `echo F|xcopy /y "c:\temp\3075.pdf" "C:\temp\newfilename.txt"`. `echo F|` pipes the answer to `is this a directory or file` question that comes up if you try to xcopy a file over to a location which does not already exist.

Comment: If i found the answer do i delete the question or answer it myself?

Comment: @blaze_125 it was a file question, it was fairly easy. I deleted the existing file and then renamed the file that was being copied. This file goes into ssis packages due to which i need just one file in that folder.

Comment: Related: [XCOPY still asking (F = file, D = directory) confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33770152)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ren "pathofthefile\file_name" "new file name"`