# Add copied file name to log file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, rename

I am copying and renaming files as below.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LOGFILE=file_transfer.log
call :Logit>>%LOGFILE% 2>&1
:Logit
echo Start time is: %date% %TIME%
set NEWFOLDER=new_folder
md "%NEWFOLDER%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("filelist.txt") do copy "%%a" ".\%NEWFOLDER%\%%b"
echo End time is: %date% %TIME%
:eof
```

When execute above script, I am getting log file as:

```
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
```

I need to get output in log file as:

```
1 file(s) copied - abc.jpg.
1 file(s) copied - xyz.jpg.
1 file(s) copied - 123.jpg.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is appearing now is the stdout of the `COPY` command. To get the desired result will require an `ECHO` command be added in the body of the `FOR` loop.

Comment: There is no need to make a CALL to the :Logit label.  But if you are going to do that then you need a `GOTO :EOF` after your `CALL` command.  And don't ever create the LABEL `:EOF` in your code.  It is not needed.  The `:EOF` label is predefined label that will always exits the current subroutine or batch program.

Comment: `xcopy` returns the copied files too before the summary line; the disadvantage is the nasty [`F`ile/`D`irectory prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770152) when you specify a single source file, you specify the destination file rather than its parent folder only (by an appended `\ `) and the destination file does not yet exist; if the source file name is kept, you could do: `xcopy "D:\source\file.ext" "D:\destination\"`...