# Windows command to copy file without any prompts for bat file

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal

I would like to make a .bat file which will make a backup for my kdbx file. I have two simple commands there.

```
cd C://Access
xcopy access4.kdbx access4.backup.kdbx /Y
```

but the second one ask me: Does access4.backup.kdbx specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?

I dont understand why Windows does not recognize the file in the source. Also I don't see any option to set it up in the command. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing simple and multiple copying of files:

`xcopy` is to be used for copying multiple files.

`copy` is to be used for copying just one file.

So, your command should be:

```
copy /Y access4.kdbx access4.backup.kdbx
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the Windows path separator is `\` but not `/` or `//`.

Then you should use `cd /D` rather than plain `cd` since you specified also a drive letter.

---

The quick solution is to use `copy` rather than `xcopy`, because it does not show such a prompt:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Access"
copy /Y "access4.kdbx" "access4.backup.kdbx"
```

However, `xcopy` features a lot of additional options in contrast to `copy`, so the latter might not help in certain situations.

---

To avoid the prompt, you could pre-create the destination file and let `xcopy` overwrite it:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Access"
>> "access4.backup.kdbx" rem/
xcopy /Y "access4.kdbx" "access4.backup.kdbx"
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770152).