# Bat file to copy Folders and Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a list of folders and files in a text file, (`%File_list%`). My batch reads from the text file for the objects to copy. I need it to copy files and folders from one within a folder (`%src_folder%`), to another folder, (`%dst_folder%`).

My current attempt copies the files, but not the folders.

Batch script:

```sh
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop
set dst_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\NewTestFolder
set file_list=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\Filelist.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%f in (%File_list%) do (
    xcopy /y /s "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
)
```

Text file:

```
Fixed Retail.xlsx
SecureFolder
```

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? How can I copy folders as well as file?

Answer (score 3):

When the source is a directory, the [`xcopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) copies its contents rather than the whole directory. To copy the whole directory, you need to alter the destination accordingly:

```cmd
xcopy /I /Y /S "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\%%f"
```

Note the `/I` option, that tells `xcopy` that the destination is not a file but a directory.

However, when the source is a single file, `xcopy` prompts you whether the destination is a file or directory when the destination does not yet exist, even when `/I` is provided (refer to [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770152)). Therefore, we have to determine what the source (`%%f`) is in advance and react adequately:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // The quoted `set` syntax protects special characters:
set "src_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop"
set "dst_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\NewTestFolder"
set "file_list=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\Filelist.txt"

rem // Append `\*` to check a directory but not a file for existence:
if not exist "%dst_folder%\*" mkdir "%dst_folder%"
rem // Use `usebackq` option and quotation to permit spaces in file path:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%File_list%") do (
    rem // Check whether source is a directory:
    if exist "%src_folder%\%%f\*" (
        rem // Source is a directory, so copy it entirely:
        xcopy /I /Y /S "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\%%f"
    ) else (
        rem // Source is a file, or it does not exist:
        xcopy /Y /S "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
    )
)
```

A bit simpler and more compact approach can be achieved when a destination file is pre-created, so the file/directory prompt does not appear:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // The quoted `set` syntax protects special characters:
set "src_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop"
set "dst_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\NewTestFolder"
set "file_list=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\Filelist.txt"

rem // Append `\*` to check a directory but not a file for existence:
if not exist "%dst_folder%\*" mkdir "%dst_folder%"
rem // Use `usebackq` option and quotation to permit spaces in file path:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%File_list%") do (
    rem // Pre-create destination file when source is a file:
    if not exist "%src_folder%\%%f\*" > "%dst_folder%\%%f" rem/
    rem // No prompt appears even when source is a file:
    xcopy /I /Y /S "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\%%f"
)
```

The easiest approach is to use the `/I` option to cover the case when source is a directory and to auto-fill the file/directory prompt for the case source is a file, but this is **locale-dependent** (for instance, `F`ile and `D`irectory for English systems, but `D`atei and `V`erzeichnis for German ones), so be careful:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // The quoted `set` syntax protects special characters:
set "src_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop"
set "dst_folder=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\NewTestFolder"
set "file_list=C:\Users\P57949\Desktop\Filelist.txt"

rem // Append `\*` to check a directory but not a file for existence:
if not exist "%dst_folder%\*" mkdir "%dst_folder%"
rem // Use `usebackq` option and quotation to permit spaces in file path:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%File_list%") do (
    rem // The `/I` option copes for directories, `echo F` for files:
    rem echo F| xcopy /I /Y /S "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\%%f"
)
```

*N. B.:*
For all of the above, I assumed that the list file `Filelist.txt` contains pure file/directory names.