# Batch Script - copy files in folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if there is a faster way of copying all files in a folder to a new folder that has today's date.

```
xcopy /s "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Files\*.*" "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Backup\08112023\"
```

Is there a way to:
a. automate the date
b. force the directory?

I get a prompt that states "specify a file name or directory name on the target (F=File, D=Directory)?"

I have been changing the date manually every single time and pressing D. Just wanting to make the process faster.

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to check out the usage information for that utility? Was there anything in that output which you tried to help you to resolve your issue? For instance, would ```/I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory```, help? As for the date, there are literally hundreds of questions and answers on this site, with the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, which provide methods of getting the date into a consistent and specific format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XCOPY still asking (F = file, D = directory) confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752732/xcopy-still-asking-f-file-d-directory-confirmation)

Comment: __XCOPY__ is deprecated since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003. There is much more powerful and robust __ROBOCOPY__ for copying multiple files. Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` for output of its usage help. In a batch file should be used this [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with its fully qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe`. __ATTENTION:__ Source and destination path should never end with ``\`` on using __ROBOCOPY__ and being enclosed in `"`.

Comment: The answers on [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124351/time-is-set-incorrectly-after-midnight) explain in full details how to get current date in a format suitable for using in a folder name independent on region/country configured for the used account. See also: [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090) My advice: Use the solution with __ROBOCOPY__!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the prompt as the command line is not told whether your target is a file or directory. This is solved by simply **adding a backslash \ to the end  of the path**. The date can be obtained using the **%date%** variable.

Something like this should work to solve your problem:

```
xcopy /s "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Files\*.*\" "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Backup\%date:~0, 2%%date:~3, 2%%date:~6, 4%\"
```

Instead of manually running the file to make backups, I'd suggest placing it in the **start-up items** and adding an **'if'** statement in case a backup has already been made for that day.

For that, something like this should work:

```
if not exist "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Backup\%date:~0, 2%%date:~3, 2%%date:~6, 4%\" xcopy /s "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Files\*.*\" "C:\Users\Frankenstein\Desktop\Backup\%date:~0, 2%%date:~3, 2%%date:~6, 4%\"
```

Start-up Folder:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Startup