# SET variable not being read in .BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, set

I have this Windows batch file and I cannot get to work it properly.
Basically I have a folder in one location and I need to copy it to another folder, but to also have the new folder name renamed.

```
@Echo off
::
set 836147398 = @Taunus_A3
:: 
Echo Copying %836147398%
xcopy "C:\Users\arrona\Desktop\Update Mods\steamapps\workshop\content\107410\836147398" "C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\%836147398%" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

So what I need is that the folder contents of 333310405 are copied to `C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\`, but as `@Taunus_A3` folder name.

It will copy the folder over and all the contents, but it is not reading the variable. It will echo "Copying 836147398" not echoing "Copying @Taunus_A3"

Comment: An environmental variable name cannot begin with a number.

Comment: ... and should not end with a space. `set var = value` will set the variable named `%var %` (with a space after) with a value `" value"` (with a space before)

Answer (score 4):

1. Get rid of spaces on either side of the `=` sign in `set "varname=varvalue"` command.
2. **Avoid naming variables with a leading number**. Read [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

Although `set "836147398=@Taunus_A3"` is a valid command,  `echo %836147398%` would display

- `@Taunus_A3` in command prompt, but
- `36147398` in a batch script, because `%8` is evaluated to the 8th supplied parameter (supposedly an empty string in most cases) and orphan trailing `%` percent sign is ignored by design.

**Solution**: use a non-cipher prefix, e.g. `_` underscore as follows:

```
set "_836147398=@Taunus_A3"
echo %_836147398%
```

Comment: ok i will have to do these all manually then, every folder name will always be a number set, steamcmd automatically creates that foldername based on which addon it downloads, no way to change that. So the only way I can see this working doing that would be to specify the first pathname as is instead of using the variable. 


xcopy "C:\Users\arrona\Desktop\Update Mods\steamapps\workshop\content\107410\836147398" "C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\%_836147398%" /s/h/e/k/f/c

Comment: The variable name can't start with a number.  That doesn't mean the folder name can't start with a number.

Comment: ok it seems to be working now, how can I get rid of this prompt 

Copying @Taunus_A3
Does C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\@Taunus_A3 specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?

Comment: @JustinThomas read [xcopy file, rename, suppress “Does xxx specify a file name…” message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3018289/3439404) thread.

Comment: `"C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\%_836147398%\"` adding a trailing \  backslash specifies **directory** as well as `/I` switch does. @JustinThomas

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the spaces on either side of the `=` sign. As you can see from the second `echo`, you're actually creating an environment variable with an *embedded space* in the name (and value, for that matter):

```
c:\pax> set 42=

c:\pax> set 42 = 57
c:\pax> echo .%42%.
.%42%.
c:\pax> echo .%42 %.
. 57.

c:\pax> set 42=57
c:\pax> echo .%42%.
.57.
```

Once that's done, the substitutions work as needed, at least on the command line<sup>(a)</sup> (although your source area is different in the code and text, you probably want to sort that out as well):

```
c:\pax> set 836147398=@Taunus_A3

c:\pax> echo xcopy "C:\Users\arrona\Desktop\Update Mods\steamapps\workshop\content\107410\836147398" "C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\%836147398%" /s/h/e/k/f/c

xcopy "C:\Users\arrona\Desktop\Update Mods\steamapps\workshop\content\107410\836147398" "C:\TCAFiles\Games\arma3exile\TCA.Mods\@Taunus_A3" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> However, one thing you should be made aware of is that `836147398` is actually a particularly *bad* variable name, partially because it will, in a script, actually use parameter names (like `%8`) in preference to `%8-something-or-other%`, but also because it's not very mnemonic.

You would be *far* better off using something like `dest_dir`, something that actually makes sense to the casual reader.

Comment: originally it was without spaces, i tried with and without and with  " "

Comment: Doing it with a space won't affect the variable without a space. It may well be you have an old variable lying around. In any case, as per the execution snippet above, doing it without spaces seems to work fine.

Comment: This would making having the set variables redundant. Is it not possible to use a set variable within an xcopy command? or is something in my windows not allowing it? its on windows server 2008 r2.

Comment: As others already stated, variable names must cannot begin with numerals in [tag:batch-files], because `%4` in `%42%` is expanded to the fourth command line argument, so your answer solves only one of two problems...

Comment: @aschipfl, it solves the exact problem as stated in the question. If I could have written an answer that would solve *every* IT-related problem, believe me, I would have. But I think SO has size limits on answers :-) In any case, I've answered that aspect as well in that the variable name chosen is, shall we say, sub-optimal (only partially because of the parameter interference problem).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:batch-file] for which your answer does not really help much, that is what I was trying to say... JosefZ attends to both issues although his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41710435) is shorter than yours... ;-)

Comment: S'Ok, @aschipfl, if it's better, vote it up. This is a meritocracy after all and I have pretty thick skin :-)