# Copying many files without extension from list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using this code below to copy files from a list. Everything is working, however doesn't work when files have NO extension. I don't know to fix it.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "src=T:\CNC-Related\CNC Programs\Biesse\Rover346\01 MAIN\S-LINE\SLE"
SET "dst=U:\Users\Edimar\PROJECTS\REPLACE LOCKING BAR\CST640\S-Line\PROGRAM\R346"
SET "file_list=.\files.txt"
SET "out=.\result.log"
echo > %out%

FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%f IN ("%file_list%") DO (
    rem just searching to find out existense of file
    WHERE /Q /R %src% "%%f"
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
        FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%s IN (`WHERE /R %src% "%%f"`) DO (
            echo "%%s => %dst%\%%f" >> %out%
            @Xcopy /y "%%s" "%dst%\%%f" 
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo %%f is not found! >> %out%
    )
)
```

Comment: Commenting out or deleting the `@echo off` line will allow you to see exactly what commands are being executed.

Comment: I tried the script at my machine and it's working. Nevertheless I would use `copy` instead of `xcopy` because `xcopy` may ask: `Does [...] specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?` like it does on my computer. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018289/xcopy-file-rename-suppress-does-xxx-specify-a-file-name-message. Further the line `echo > %out%` does not clear the file but it writes the current state of `echo` in the file. Use `break>%out%` to clear a file.

Comment: Hi Andre, I modified my script to uso copy instead of xcopy, but still not working for files without extension. Please see below: U:\Users\Edimar\PROJECTS\REPLACE LOCKING BAR\CST64
rem just searching to find out existense of file
 WHERE /Q /R T:\CNC-Related\CNC Programs\Biesse\Ro
279R01"
 IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (FOR /F "usebackq eol=|
NC-Related\CNC Programs\Biesse\Rover346\01 MAIN\S-
echo "%s => U:\Users\Edimar\PROJECTS\REPLACE LOCKI
346\SLE279R01"  1>>.\result.log

) )  ELSE (echo SLE279R01 is not found!  1>>.\resu
)
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @EdimarFerri Did I just see a bunch of randomly generated, unformatted text in the last comment? All I see is just your `REM`ed the entire code and the error.