# "Proper" way to find path to C# compiler?

Tags: c#, windows, compiler-construction, registry, csc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - How to get csc.exe path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660512/c-how-to-get-csc-exe-path)

Is there a "proper" way to find the path to the C# compiler on a given system?

E.g. for Java, the "proper" way is to use the `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft` registry key to go through all the different JDKs and their locations, rather than assuming that everything is in `%ProgramFiles%\Java`.

Is there a similar method for C#?

Comment: @Bala: Ah, my mistake; it's indeed a duplicate. Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list installed frameworks in:
*HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NetFramework*

And on File system *%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework*

Remembering only, you can access compiler services through the .net classes themselves.

Comment: +1 yeah I guess there's not much of a more direct way to do it, thanks...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Comment: The KB article only works assuming I'm doing this from C#. Which doesn't really work because I'm doing this from JScript.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something less system dependent:

```
string cscPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),"csc.exe");
```

Comment: This only works assuming I'm doing this from C#. Which doesn't really work because I'm doing this from JScript. :P

Comment: Oh. Then why the C# tag? It's quite confusing.

Comment: Really? Sorry, next time I'll tag questions about the C# compiler with JScript instead.

Comment: This gets the path of your running assembly, which isn't necessarily the path where `csc.exe` resides. The compiler is part of the .NET Framework, which is embedded in the Windows directory. If you have installed Roslyn, it may also be in Program Files (x86).