# I want to create a dll of .cs file by code

Tags: c#

I want to create a dll of .cs file by code means by programming in c# can any one help me out how to do it 
means that i have a two class "Class1" and "Class2" and i want to create dll for class1 by programming so how it will be possible for me
please help me out to do it.

EDIT:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe");

info.Arguments = @" /out:E:\pratik\file option\Class1.dll Class1.cs";
info.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(info); 
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have use this code to create dll it is running but i am not getiing dll on given path

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Are you trying to write a compiler in C# for C#?

Comment: @H2CO3 That's how it should be done, isn't it?

Comment: please, as others already said, point what you tried, what you want, and what's wrong with the result you've got so far.

Comment: @H2CO3 No i just want to make a DLL for individual Classes suppose i have a two class in my application and i want to make a dll for the first Class by CMD it is possible but by code in C# how it will be possible for me ?

Comment: change `info.Arguments = @" /out:E:\pratik\file option\Class1.dll Class1.cs";` to `info.Arguments = @" /out:E:\pratik\fileoption\Class1.dll Class1.cs";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [compiler as services - CodeDomCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) feature to create dll/exe on the fly.

[How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)

[Compiling wiht CodeDom - Article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7119/Compiling-with-CodeDom)

Alternative approach is to compile files [CSC.exe command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx) to create the library. For this you need to launch new process with appropriate arguments.

```
 Process.Start( Path.Combine(GetCscFolderLocation() ,"csc"),  "/target:library File1.cs File2.cs /reference: <reference 1> <reference2> ..."

 string GetCscFolderLocation()
 {
 // Getting CSC location
 }
```

Getting CSC.exe folder location is tricky. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6660569/649524) to get an idea.

Following example starts text file in default editor.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.e‌​xe", @"/target:library /out:C:\test\test.dll c:\test\File.cs");
```

Comment: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx" This Link is not usable for me i just want to create DLL for individual Classes.

Comment: You can just use csc.exe tool in that case. I will update the answer for this approach.

Comment: i have already use this link or this code but this is creating only .exe not .dll

Comment: ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe");

            info.Arguments = @" /out:E:\pratik\file option\Class1.dll Class1.cs";
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(info);

            Console.ReadLine();   I have use this code to create dll it is running but i am not getiing dll on given path

Comment: Are you able to compile the files from command line? Also select directory path with spaces. (fileoption instead of file option) If yes, call Process.WaitForExit and check Process.ExitCode

Comment: i am getting a error after given this one : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:library /out:myfile.dll Class2.cs ----"the file could not find the path"----

Comment: First try to run in command prompt. If this error is coming there, it means path is not correct (Class2.cs does not exist in current directory, or path of csc.exe is wrong)

Comment: no when i will use only that path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe " compiler will run but i have to get output of the dll means that location to get dll so i have given ---"/target:library /out:myfile.dll Class2.cs"---

Comment: try /out:c:\myfile.dll c:\Class2.cs, and copy Class2.cs to c:\

Comment: i already tried this one,but no success

Comment: I have tried following, and it has created file successfuly.`Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe", @"/target:library /out:C:\test\test.dll c:\test\File.cs");` . Seems like issue in your file or may be Path is too long (more than 255)

Comment: It seems like it working.I assign the parameter in **ProcessStartInfo** object and then call Process.Start(**object**) and its done.

Comment: But i accept you,as you help me to figure out the problem,Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with final command.

Answer (score 0):

go to new project in visual studio

select class library name it as you want

now, put method, properties in that class what ever you need

build it.

Add this reference to your project.

Comment: No i just want to create single DLL for individual Classes.