# How to list files with a timestamp greater than x

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a list of file names whereby the `LastModified` timestamp is greater than a set value.

I think, I am very close with the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

REM delete existing output file
for %%f in (_modified) do if exist %%f.txt del %%f.txt

REM hard code timstamp threshold
set lastTime=20140801000000
echo "lastTime=%lastTime%"

REM set folder to CWD
set "folder=%CD:~2%"
echo "folder=%folder%"

REM search files in folder with extension 'jpg'
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1*" %%a in (
        '"wmic datafile where (path='%folder:\=\\%\\' AND Extension='jpg') get 'File Name',LastModified"'
        ) do (
    FOR /F "delims=." %%B in ("%%b") do (
        if %%B LEQ %lastTime% (echo "%%B LEQ1") else (echo "%%B GEQ1")
        if %%B GEQ %lastTime% (echo "%%B GEQ2") else (echo "%%B LEQ2") 
        if %%B GEQ %lastTime% (
            echo %%B %%a>> _modified.txt))
)
```

However, for a folder which contains 2 jpg files, one of which has a last modified of 2010-02-22 and the other 2014-08-14 the script prints:

```
"lastTime=20140801000000"
"folder=\test"
"20100222210624 LEQ1"
"20100222210624 GEQ2"
"20140814155354 LEQ1"
"20140814155354 GEQ2"
```

And the output file contains both file names instead of the expected result of just one.

Obviously the LEQ/GEQ comparison is not working as I expect, but I'm not sure what is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use

```
if "%%B" LEQ "%lastTime%"
```

or

```
if x%%B LEQ x%lastTime%
```

which will force alphabetical-mode comparison. I'd suggest that `cmd` is attempting to compare the values as INT32s and the values are converted to gobbledegook as they're evaluted using `cmd`'s range limits

Answer (score 0):

(it is not answer, but I can't add so long comment)

Could you check, that LEQ/GEQ works correctly in simple case (without any loops and file operations)? I.e. could you run following code?

```
@echo off
set a=20100222210624
set b=20140814155354
set lastTime=20140801000000        
if %a% LEQ %lastTime% (echo "%a% LEQ1") else (echo "%a% GEQ1")
if %b% GEQ %lastTime% (echo "%b% GEQ2") else (echo "%b% LEQ2")
```

On my side it prints following result (as expected):

```
"20100222210624 LEQ1"
"20140814155354 GEQ2"
```

If it is the same on your side, we should search the problem somewhere else.

Also [here](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) you can find something about comparation:

> IF only parses numbers when one of the compare-op operators (EQU, NEQ,
>   LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ) is used.  The == comparison operator always
>   results in a string comparison.
>
> This is an important difference because if you compare numbers as
>   strings it can lead to unexpected results: "2" will be greater than
>   "19" and "026" will be greater than "26".
>
> Correct numeric comparison: IF 2 GEQ 15 echo "bigger"
>
> Using parenthesis or quotes will force a string comparison: IF (2) GEQ
>   (15) echo "bigger" IF "2" GEQ "15" echo "bigger"

(also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687014/how-do-i-compare-timestamps-of-files-in-a-dos-batch-script) in the accepted answer you can find another way to compare dates of files (i.e. you can create temporary file for such comparations))