# Comparing last modified timestamps to update a file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I want to create a batch file which will read a .log file, then picks up errors from it and append to a .txt file.
But I don't want the batch to rewrite .txt every time, so now I am looking to compare the last modification timestamps of both these files and then append the latest updation only.
Following is the batch file

```
@echo off


color 3
cls

@FOR %%A IN ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log") DO @(ECHO=%%~tA& set timestamp=%%~tA)

echo %timestamp%


@FOR %%A IN ("D:\error.txt") DO @(ECHO=%%~tA& set timestamp2=%%~tA)

echo %timestamp2%

if %timestamp% gtr %timestamp2% (

set DirToSearch="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs"
set LineToRead="error"

pushd %DirToSearch%



for /r %%f in (error.log) do (
For /F "tokens=*" %%l in ('Findstr /L /I %LineToRead% "%%f"') do (
 if %%l equ " " (
    echo File:"%%f" is Not OK >> D:\FileStatus.txt
) else (
    echo Line: %%l>>D:\error.txt

        )
                  )
)

Goto :End

:End
popd
)
pause
exit
```

Now here I am unable to compare the timestamps
It would be great help if anyone contributes to achieve this.

Comment: Best way to compare timestamps is to compare with unixtimestamps. Maybe you look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare timestamps of files in a DOS batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687014/how-do-i-compare-timestamps-of-files-in-a-dos-batch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set "DirToSearch=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs"
set "processedfile=D:\error.txt"
set "LineToRead=error"

pushd %DirToSearch%
COPY "%processedfile%" ".\processedfile.log" >nul 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od *.log') do (
 if /i "%%a"=="error.log" goto end
 if /i "%%a"=="processedfile.log" goto process
)

:process
for /r %%f in (error.log) do (
For /F "tokens=*" %%l in ('Findstr /L /I /C:"%LineToRead%" "%%f"') do (
 if %%l equ " " (
    echo File:"%%f" is Not OK >> D:\FileStatus.txt
) else (
    echo Line: %%l>>D:\error.txt

        )
                  )
)

:end
del "processedfile.log"
popd

pause
exit
```

I've removed the fluff from the code.

Note that after an `@echo off` statement, `@` at the start of a command is redundant (`@command` means "don't echo the command)

The `setlocal` command ensures that changes made to the environment are discarded when the batch terminates.

Note the new position of the quotes - to ensure that the value assigned to the variable does not include any possible stray trailing spaces.

After switching directory, the processed file is `copied` to the current directory in a unique name (whatever name you choose, as long as it has a `.log` extension) - this places a copy of the file in the log directory, so that the magic can be performed.

The `dir` command reports the names of the `.log` files found; `/od` provides the list in timestamp order. Therefore, whichever of the two files `error.log` and `processedfile.log` occurs first in the list will cause the code to branch to either `process` to process the data (the `processedfile.log` file is earlier than the `error.log` so new data has been added) or `end` (`error.log` is earlier, so no new data has been added)

I've made only one minor change to your `findstr` - added `/c:` and quoted the target string. This is largely redundant, but if you change the string to include a space, it provides a verbatim target for `findstr`. The remainder of that processing as as it was as I don't know the exact details of the processing required.

Note that in your code, `DirToSearch` and `LineToRead` were being re-assigned **within** the code block (series of lines enclosed in parentheses). This would not work because the entire code block is parsed then executed, and the parsing process replaces any `%var%` with its value *at parse time*. Your code failed to fail - because you were not using a `setlocal`, once the code had run, the variables remained assigned, and the code on future runs would use the value assigned in the prior run.

Note that `:` is not required in a `goto` except in the specific `goto :eof` which means "go to end-of-file".

Your `goto end` is redundant, as `end` directly follows the `goto` - but again, it fails to fail. A label within a code block terminates the block. In this case, it was irrelevant since nothing important followed the label.

Having reached the label `:end`, the process now deletes the copy of the processed file  and pops the original directory back with a `popd` instruction.

Comment: hi magoo thanks for explaining with such a deep interest, I learned a lot more things from your answer. Thanks for supporting