# In BAT file, compare files by modification time: "if file1 is-older-than file2 do"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I try to imitate in a Windows batch file the behavior of `make`:

```
if file.obj is-older-than file.c compile file.c
```

How to express this in a batch file? I only know

```
if not exist file.obj compile file.c
```

which is not the same.

**EDIT**: This question already has an answer: A similar question has been asked, with the best answer (in my view) being in a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29505781/3814740).

Comment: Yes, a similar question has been asked, but this is a specific case of that question, and the real answer is in a comment on one (and not the chosen one!) answer to that question, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505781/3814740. I suggest to keep the question, and this comment will direct the readers to the best answer.

Comment: Here is a link that will explain:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687014/how-do-i-compare-timestamps-of-files-in-a-dos-batch-script

Comment: The best answer there is buried in a comment to one of the answers. I copy it here: `xcopy /DYLR src "dst*" | findstr /BC:"0" >nul && @echo dst is newer`.