# Windows Batch Script: why is the syntax of this IF command incorrect?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

### Description

In an attempt to print `Init has already been made` to the screen if the file `init.marker` is newer than the files `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` using a Windows Batch Script ([where the code below comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687076/9343156)):

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O:D init.marker setup.py setup.cfg') DO SET last_modified_file=%%i
IF "%last_modified_file%"=="init.marker"(
    ECHO Init has already been made
)
```

I came accross a `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` error.

---

### Where the error comes from

Let's say we wrote the above mentioned Batch Script to a file named `make_init.cmd` which lies in the same directory as the files `init.marker`, `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`.
(We can create those files using the Batch Script see [1]. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1702790/9343156) for more information on how to create empty files using a Batch Script.) Let's use cmd.exe to run it, which gives us following output:

```
User> make_init.cmd
User> FOR /F %i IN ('DIR /B /O:D init.marker setup.py setup.cfg') DO SET last_modified_file=%i
User> SET last_modified_file=init.marker
User> SET last_modified_file=setup.py
User> SET last_modified_file=setup.cfg
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
User> IF "setup.cfg"=="init.marker" (
```

Let's first see if our FOR statement works as intended by running the same script but swapping out the IF statement for a simple ECHO statement. (See [2])
The output is what we would expect:

```
User> make_init.cmd
User> COPY /B NUL  1>init.marker
User> COPY /B NUL  1>setup.py
User> COPY /B NUL  1>setup.cfg
User> FOR /F %i IN ('DIR /B /O:D init.marker setup.py setup.cfg') DO SET last_modified_file=%i
User> SET last_modified_file=init.marker
User> SET last_modified_file=setup.py
User> SET last_modified_file=setup.cfg
User> ECHO setup.cfg
setup.cfg
```

As far as I understand, this means that the mentioned command which is incorrect must be
`IF "%last_modified_file%"=="init.marker" (` which evaluates to `IF "setup.cfg"=="init.marker" (`

How come then, that in any other circumstance (see [3]) such an IF statement is totally valid?

---

### Question

What is wrong with the Syntax of the above IF command?

---

### Attachments

[1] Script extension to create the needed files.

```
COPY /B NUL > init.marker
COPY /B NUL > setup.py
COPY /B NUL > setup.cfg
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O:D init.marker setup.py setup.cfg') DO SET last_modified_file=%%i
IF "%last_modified_file%"=="init.marker"(
    ECHO Init has already been made
)
```

[2] Swap out the IF statement with an ECHO statement

```
COPY /B NUL > init.marker
COPY /B NUL > setup.py
COPY /B NUL > setup.cfg
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O:D init.marker setup.py setup.cfg') DO SET last_modified_file=%%i
ECHO %last_modified_file%
```

[3] Simple test Script for an IF statement

```
:: Filename:        test_if.cmd
:: How to execute:  test_if.cmd hello

IF "%1"=="hello" (
    SET the_greeting_message=Greetings, traveller.
)
IF "%the_greeting_message%"=="Greetings, traveller." (
    ECHO %the_greeting_message%
)
```

Comment: Insert a space before the `(` character on the `if` command line.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart wow this is disappointing and somewhat embarrassing for me ^^. You fixed it, thank you very much!
Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Removed inapplicable `bash` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a space before the trailing `(` character on the `if` command line:

```
IF "%last_modified_file%"=="init.marker"(
```

Insert a space before the trailing `(` character and it should parse correctly.